# How to pass and access C pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, printf, string-literals, function-definition

How can I make this code work. Address in main is different inside func as well as the value is not the sam ?

```
const char *Like="CO";
void main(){
 printf("%d",Like); // o/p 4206935
 printf("%c\n\n",(Like[0]));   // o/p C
 func(conLen);
}
void func(const char *chP){
printf("%d",chP); // o/p  4206938
printf("%c\n\n",(chp[0]));  // o/p  %
}
```

Comment: Argument `conLen` is unrelated to `Like` and is not defined in the code anyway.

Comment: @Anter The variable chp is not declared.

Comment: Please keep the return type of `main` to be `int` , `main` can never have a return type of  `void`,`conLen` is undefined declare and assign it somewhere

Comment: Additionally, `%d` is an incorrect field directive for a pointer.  Use `%p`, instead: `printf("%p", (void *) Like);`.

Comment: @AbhilekhGautam — on Windows, `void main()` is a documented and hence acceptable form for `main()` — as in, the compiler will accept it.  It is better not to use it, but be careful of overstating your case.  See [What should `main()` return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/204476/15168) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

The presented program shall not compile at least because there are used several undeclared names.

> How can I make this code work. Address in main is different inside
> func as well as the value is not the sam ?

It seems you are trying to achieve something like the following

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char *Like = "CO";

void func( const char *chP );

int main(void) 
{
    printf( "%p\n", ( void * )Like );
    printf( "%c\n", Like[0] );
    func( Like );
}

void func( const char *chP )
{
    printf( "%p\n", ( void * )chP );
    printf( "%c\n", chP[0] );
}
```

The program output might look like

```
0x555a23f0d004
C
0x555a23f0d004
C
```

As you can see the outputted addresses and values in `main` and in the function `func` are the same.

Pay attention to that to output a value of a pointer you should use the conversion specifier `p`.

And according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be  declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about passing and accessing a pointer (char*) you can easily do it the following way:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void func(char*);
int main(){

char* Like ="hello";
func(Like);

return 0;

}

void func(char* a){

printf("The string is %s",a);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

**I am assuming that you want to pass the pointer to the function**

while calling the function `func` pass the pointer with it like `func(Like)`

Apologies, if I didn't understand your question correctly.